# Cursor style doesn't update when element dynamically moved under it

Tags: javascript, css, dom, cursor, dhtml

When an element is dynamically moved under the location of the cursor, the cursor style doesn't update **until the user moves the cursor at least 1px**. For example, say I have some Javascript that moves this `div` directly under the cursor on mouse click.

```
<div style="cursor:move">hover me!</div>
```

If you hover over the `div`, the cursor will change to `move`. However, if you click and the `div` gets moved under your cursor, the cursor remains the default arrow until you move the cursor at least 1px.

[Here's a JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/afdna02q/)

Is there a way to directly change the cursor via Javascript or force the cursor to update properly?

Comment: Your fiddle works fine in my Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hm. I'm on OSX. Behavior is present in Chrome 36.0.1985.125 as well as Safari 6.1.4, but not Firefox. Maybe it's just a Mac/WebKit thing?

Comment: I am using a Windows machine and I am seeing the effect that you've described in IE10.  Other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera) work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarily manually setting the cursor to move seems to work.
As soon as the mouse is moved again, the JS-applied CSS is cleared + normal behavior takes over.

http://jsfiddle.net/x0nbvt25/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click", function(c){
        $(".drag").offset({
            top: c.pageY-8,
            left: c.pageX-25
        });
        $("body").css("cursor", "move");
        $("body").mousemove(function(){
            $("body").css("cursor", '');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why fill the hole when you can patch it over with drywall?

[I'd suggest testing this method in different browsers if this is going to be on a production site]